# How to use node-sass in developing VSCode extensions?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-sass

I'm trying to make a VSCode extension for compiling SASS.

However, I have no experience developing VSCode extensions and node.js, so I could not find out the cause of an error with node-sass.

extension.ts:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    var ns = require('node-sass');

    let disposables = [];

    disposables.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        'simpleSass.compileSass', () => {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Compilation finished normally.');
        }
    ));

    context.subscriptions.push(
        ...disposables
    );
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

Error message:

> Activating extension 'publisher.name' failed: Node Sass
>   does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with
>   Unsupported runtime (73) For more information on which environments
>   are supported please see:
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.13.1.

However, I could compile SASS from the command line using the same version of node-sass on the same computer.
I wondered if it's not an environmental problem.

How can I use node-sass in VSCode extensions?

(Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. There may be something strange.)

Comment: Maybe is your node version. The node version used by vscode is not the same as the one you have installed for command line.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I used the same node.js. I operated Git Bash only from the VSCode terminal.

Comment: A terminal inside VSCode is still a terminal: Go to `About Visual Studio Code`, and check what node version is there. Later in your terminal type: `node --version`.

Comment: Sorry, I understand. I executed `[Help]-[About]` on VSCode, and the dialog showed that `Node.js: 12.4.0`. And the command `node --version` returns v10.16.0 on the terminal of VSCode.